# After delete a large file in linux system I can still see that the space was not released

Tags: linux, file

I have done the following command:

```
[equalum@eqclstr006a ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        30G  1.9G   28G   7% /
devtmpfs        6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           6.9G   49M  6.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       497M   62M  436M  13% /boot
/dev/sdb1        28G   45M   26G   1% /mnt/resource
/dev/sdc        148G  2.0G  139G   2% /eq
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /run/user/1001
**/dev/sdd1       493G  2.2G  465G   1% /data**
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I have seen that the file space is 2.2G
then I deleted the file by using this command: sudo rm -rf /data/lfs.csv

when I checked the space again on this partition (sdd1) I have noticed that the space the file got was not release:

```
[equalum@eqclstr006a ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        30G  1.9G   28G   7% /
devtmpfs        6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           6.9G   49M  6.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       497M   62M  436M  13% /boot
/dev/sdb1        28G   45M   26G   1% /mnt/resource
/dev/sdc        148G  2.0G  139G   2% /eq
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /run/user/1001
/dev/sdd1       493G  2.2G  465G   1% /data
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /run/user/1000
```

how can I release the wanted space back?

Comment: This question is off-topic, but is there a running program that still has the file open?

Comment: No... it's a bash shell script that run and create lfs.csv in an endless loop till it stopped manually after I stop the script I delete the file I can see that the partition where the file was created is still full like I never deleted the file.

Answer (score 2):

OK the solution for this problem is to identify which processes hold the file, perform the following command:

```
    [user123@eqclstr006a ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/lsof | grep deleted
tuned        915                  root    7u      REG                8,2       4096   50331727 /tmp/ffiyukbzX (deleted)
gmain        915   1116           root    7u      REG                8,2       4096   50331727 /tmp/ffiyukbzX (deleted)
tuned        915   1118           root    7u      REG                8,2       4096   50331727 /tmp/ffiyukbzX (deleted)
tuned        915   1119           root    7u      REG                8,2       4096   50331727 /tmp/ffiyukbzX (deleted)
tuned        915   1120           root    7u      REG                8,2       4096   50331727 /tmp/ffiyukbzX (deleted)
tail      124110               equalum    3r      REG               8,49 2154610690         13 /data/lfs.csv (deleted)
lfs.sh    125254               equalum    1w      REG               8,49   37589318         14 /data/lfs.csv (deleted)
tail      125256               equalum    3r      REG               8,49   37589318         14 /data/lfs.csv (deleted)
```

release all relevant PID by:

```
kill 915 124110 125254 125256
```